# Chamando um Array de uma função Pública na View do Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, funções

Tenho essa função pública na `Controller`:

```
public function faturar() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';


    if ($this->form_validation->run('receita') == false) 
    {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $vencimento = $this->input->post('vencimento');
        $recebimento = $this->input->post('recebimento');

        try {

            $vencimento = explode('/', $vencimento);
            $vencimento = $vencimento[2].'-'.$vencimento[1].'-'.$vencimento[0];

            if($recebimento != null){
                $recebimento = explode('/', $recebimento);
                $recebimento = $recebimento[2].'-'.$recebimento[1].'-'.$recebimento[0];

            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           $vencimento = date('Y/m/d'); 
        }

        $data = array(
            'descricao' => set_value('descricao'),
            'valor' => $this->input->post('valor'),
            'clientes_id' => $this->input->post('clientes_id'),
            'data_vencimento' => $vencimento,
            'data_pagamento' => $recebimento,
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('recebido'),
            'cliente_fornecedor' => set_value('cliente'),
            'forma_pgto' => $this->input->post('formaPgto'),
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo')
        );

        if ($this->os_model->add('lancamentos',$data) == TRUE) { 

            $os = $this->input->post('os_id'); 

            $this->db->set('faturado',1);
            $this->db->set('valorTotal',$this->input->post('valor'));
            $this->db->where('idOs', $os);
            $this->db->update('os'); 

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','OS faturada com sucesso!');
            $json = array('result'=>  true);
            echo json_encode($json);
            die();
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar faturar OS.');
            $json = array('result'=>  false);
            echo json_encode($json);
            die();
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar faturar OS.');
    $json = array('result'=>  false);
    echo json_encode($json);

}
```

E na View tenho esse código:

```
<li>
    <span><h5>Técnico Responsável</h5></span>
    <span><strong>Nome: </strong> <?php echo $result->nome?></span> <br/>
    <span><strong>OS: </strong><?php echo $result->idOs ?></br></span>
    <span><strong>Data Inicial: </strong><?php echo $dataInicial ?></br></span>
    <span><strong>Data Final: </strong><?php echo $dataFinal ?></br></span>
    <span><strong>Data da Impressão desse documento: </strong><?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?></br></span>
    <span><strong><h4>Status da OS: <?php echo $result->status ?></h4></strong></span>
    <?php  if(faturar(baixado)=1) { echo '<span><strong><h5>Fatura Paga</h5></strong></span>'; } ?>     
</li>
```

Na última linha da view, onde está escrito `<?php  if(faturar(baixado)=1)`, estou querendo chamar a chave 'baixado' do array $data e verificar no banco se o registro foi baixado ou não.

Existe uma maneira pra eu fazer isso direto na `View`, sem a necessidade de criar uma função na `Model`, e depois na `Controller` e depois na `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem coisa errada ai! Veja:

O método `faturar()` se encontra no Controller. Então primeiro que você não irá conseguir acessar esse método sem carregar seu `Controller` na `View`, e segundo, isso está conceitualmente errado, pois a `View` não "enxerga" o `Controller`, veja imagem no final da resposta, e terceiro mesmo se você fizesse isso, está sendo passando um argumento `baixado` pro método que não está definido na assinatura.

Você não mostrou de onde estão vindo os dados que estão sendo inseridos na `li`, mas dá pra subentender que vem de uma consulta; você mostrou o método `faturar()` que apenas retornar um campo booleano. Você deve fazer um `select` de tal forma que já entregue para a View se a ordem de serviço está baixada ou não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Murilo. Vou seguir seus conselhos e tentar por aqui e qualquer coisa te aviso.